# How to shotern my coding in android?

Tags: java, android, c

recently i found my coding like ruby so i want to improve my coding style can anyone suggest a good tutorial or some tips

here is my sample rubbish coding :

```
class AA{
int flag;

if (flag == 1){
method1();
}else if(flag == 2){
method2();
}... It ll go like that till method 10

/**
*In Method
*/

method1()
{
display11111111;
}
method2{
display2222222;
}... it ll go .....
```

this question may not be gud but am in the stage to ask pls help to improve

Comment: but what u wanna do ? ur aim ? what does above code provide output?

Comment: @Monica i juz want single method nd i want to reuse that

Comment: look for below answers..i think these will work

Comment: @Monica Thnx for ur instant rply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Custom Function which can be reusable in future:

```
class AA{
int flag;

functionName(flag);
```

/**
*In Method
*/

```
functionName(int flag)
{
 switch (flag) {
        case 1:
            display11111111;
            break;
        case 2:
            display2222222;
            break;
           ... it ll go .....
        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine than my code thnx. Is dar any other option??

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically want to use Swtich/Case statements to control the logic flow. Although you typically wouldn't find a main method in an Android program (see below), the same idea still applies.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int flag = 0; //Change the variable to switch to a different case
    switch (flag) {
        case 0: method1() ;break;
        case 1: method2() ;break;
        case 2: method3() ;break;
        case 3: method4() ;break;
        //And so on

        default: /*Default Operation*/ ;break;
    }       
}

public static void method1(){
    //TODO
}
public static void method2(){
    //TODO
}
public static void method3(){
    //TODO
}
public static void method4(){
    //TODO
}
```